# htaccess ,url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

Anyone can help me to rewrite links above, im made custom script but now have problem to rewrite this, im start htaccess with something like this...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?query=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?query=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

But this not work, i have server error 500...

this is what i need to rewrite..

```
http://site.com/index.php?page=1 ==> http://site.com/1
http://site.com/index.php?type=news&page=1 ==> http://site.com/news/1
http://site.com/index.php?query=searching ==> http://site.com/searching 
http://site.com/index.php?query=searching&page=1  ==> http://site.com/searching/1
```

Comment: If you have a 500, you will need to look in your server's error log to find out what the error was.

Comment: I'm on shared host dont have permission to check this logs

Comment: Your shared host doesn't place an error log in your own space, limited to your own virtual host? That is commonly done.

Comment: Yea for 500 error i dont have any logs created, but i think its not a server fault, i think its problem here

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]`

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?query=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Try these - I think you have the rules back to front:

http://site.com/1 executes http://site.com/index.php?page=1

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

http://site.com/news/1 executes http://site.com/index.php?type=news&page=1

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) /index.php?type=news&page=$1 [L]
```

http://site.com/searching executes http://site.com/index.php?query=searching

```
RewriteRule ^searching/?$ /index.php?query=searching [L]
```

http://site.com/searching/1 executes http://site.com/index.php?query=searching&page=1

```
RewriteRule ^searching/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?query=searching&page=$1 [L]
```